# Control NSNumber with NSSlider

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber, nsslider

I have an NSSlider, and want it to control an NSNumber in an app which will be created in Xcode5.  Tried the code below, which returned no errors, but the slider did not change the NSNumber's value:

```
float sliderValue = ([sender floatValue]);
[myQCView setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sliderValue] forInputKey:@"inputNumber"];
```

I also tried to add the .value for the sliderValue, but this returned an error:

```
float sliderValue = ([sender floatValue]);
[myQCView setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:sliderValue.value] forInputKey:@"inputNumber"];
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: what is myQCView ? Also sliderGives you integerValue. So whats the problem.

Comment: Bind the two objects using KVC.

Comment: replace `numberWithInt` with `numberWithFloat`

Answer (score 0):

```
float sliderValue = [sender floatValue];
[myQCView setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:sliderValue.value] forInputKey:@"inputNumber"];
```

Comment: So you are saying an `NSNumber` created using an `int` won't work, but one created using a `float` will?  I doubt that.

Comment: Thank you.

    [myQCView setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:sliderValue.value] forInputKey:@"inputNumber"];

Just tried the above and got an error:  'Member reference base type 'float' is not a structure or union".

This error disappears when I remove '.value' from sliderValue...  but then the slider does not change the parameter value.

Any suggestions on how to receive the float value without the error ?